# Where does a Blackberry Torch stores the current wallpaper image?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

I have a Blackberry Torch 9800 that displays as wallpaper a photo that I saved on the micro SD card. Recently the micro SD card had a problem and some of the stored photos were lost, including the one that I use as wallpaper. I already tried fixing the micro SD card filesystem with no luck.

Though currently the photo is still displayed as wallpaper, it does not longer exists on the SD card, so I'm assuming that there must be a copy of it stored somewhere in the internal memory.

Does anyone knows where the Blackberry OS stores the current wallpaper image and how to access to it?

Thank you all for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after searching for a while on the device I found the wallpaper file. Good news is that I found the wallpaper photo. Bad news is that it has low resolution (480x360 - Blackberry screen  size). Anyway, here's how to find it:

- Open File Explorer
- Click on "File Folders"
- Then click on "Device Memory"
- Press Menu button and select "Show hidden files"
- Then browse through appdata->rim->homescreen
- There are two files called wallpaper.dat and wallpaper_landscape.dat
- Copy the files and rename them to wallpaper.jpg and wallpaper_landscape.jpg
- Open the files.